# Generate a CrypoAPI (CAPI) Private Key

Tags: asp.net-core, encryption, certificate, x509certificate, cryptoapi

I am trying to implement encryption at rest using an [IXmlEncryptor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/extensibility/key-management?view=aspnetcore-3.1#ixmlencryptor).  Specifically using a CertificateEncryptor.  (This is part of the IXmlRepository system for sharing keys for decrypting cookies and general [key management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/implementation/key-management?view=aspnetcore-3.1) in ASP.NET Core.)

This [docs page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/implementation/key-encryption-at-rest?view=aspnetcore-3.1#x509-certificate) discusses using an X.509 certificate for this purpose.

It indicates that "only certificates with **CAPI private keys** are supported".

Googling that shows that CAPI means Microsoft CryptAPI.  But I can not find much more about it, and what I can find seems to be C++ related.

My "certificates guy" basically told me this when I asked him what a "CAPI private key" was:

> Microsoft generated PFX files converted to x509 have a password.  That would be the only thing I could think of.

Is that the same thing?

If not, **how is a X.509 certificate with a CAPI private key created?**

NOTE: The X.509 Certificate is the only option of those listed on the [docs page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/implementation/key-encryption-at-rest?view=aspnetcore-3.1#x509-certificate) that will work on a Linux machine (container).  That is why I am not looking at any of the other (possibly easier) options.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your "certificate guy" is incorrect.

Microsoft has two versions of cryptography susbsytems: Legacy CrypotAPI (simply CryptoAPI or CAPI) and Cryptography Next Generation (CNG, CAPI2).

CrytpoAPI was invented in Windows 2000. Legacy CryptoAPI is morally outdated with no support for ECC, SHA2: only RSA/legacy DSA (up to 1k long keys), DES/3DES, RCx, no built-in AES. Keys are stored in legacy Cryptography Service Provider (or CSP). Though, in Windows Vista+, a legacy CSP with SHA2 and AES was added to help older applications to utilize them without much changes in code.

CNG was first introduced back in 2007 in Windows Vista/Windows Server 2008 and is really a good stuff: it is pretty extensible, with native support of NSA Suite B cryptography (ECC asymmetric keys, SHA2 algorithm groups), key isolation, unified set of BCrypt functions and must more. Most CNG-only APIs include `NCrypt`, `BCrypt`, `CNG`, `NG` suffixes/prefixes in their names to explicitly say it is CNG APIs. In CNG, keys are stored in redesigned CSP called Key Storage Provider (KSP) to distinguish it from legacy CSP, because they are not same (though, there is a one-way bridge to access CSP from KSP, but not otherwise).

However, .NET was struggling in adopting CNG and made it more-or-less usable only in .NET 4.7 (implementations existed before, but with known limitations) and 3rd party applications support CNG only when they explicitly add support for it, because CNG uses different APIs and .NET Framework upgrade doesn't make application CNG-capable.

This was a bit of theory on what is the difference between CAPI and CAPI2.

And your documentation says that it requires certificates that use legacy CSP to store private keys. When creating in Windows, legacy CSP is used when one of the following providers is used:

```
Microsoft Base Cryptographic Provider v1.0
Microsoft Base DSS and Diffie-Hellman Cryptographic Provider
Microsoft Base DSS Cryptographic Provider
Microsoft Base Smart Card Crypto Provider
Microsoft DH SChannel Cryptographic Provider
Microsoft Enhanced Cryptographic Provider v1.0
Microsoft Enhanced DSS and Diffie-Hellman Cryptographic Provider
Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider
Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider <- this is preferred for legacy CSPs
Microsoft Strong Cryptographic Provider
```

You can specify any of them when creating certificate (key pair) on Windows. For example, when using `New-SelfSignedCertificate` PowerShell cmdlet (which defaults to CNG KSP), or certreq.exe tool to generate request to be signed by external CA. This part depends on tooling you use to create certificates/certificate requests.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!  These are great details!  I find it crazy that the (much newer) .Net Core IXmlEncryptor only supports a Windows 2000 era solution!  I am quite confused why they would do that in their "rewrite" of .Net to .Net Core.

Comment: Interesting. These APIs are pretty new (.NET Core only). Maybe, there are deep dependencies on older stuff, I don't know. But it is another question.

Comment: The CAPI/CNG choice is as explicit in the managed world as in the native world. Between two implementations of `System.Security.Cryptography.RSA`, the  `RSACryptoServiceProvider` class works on top of legacy CryptoAPI, while `RSAKey` is backed by CNG.

Answer (score 1):

This is a working example using the `Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider` for generating the certificate as suggested in Crypt32's answer. The keys are stored in the database. Tested on Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS.

Using ASP.NET Core 3.1. Developing on Windows 10 and hosting on Ubuntu 18.04.5.

Using PowerShell as administrator

`New-SelfSignedCertificate -provider "Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider" -FriendlyName "site_key" -KeyAlgorithm RSA -KeyLength 2048 -NotAfter (Get-Date).AddYears(30) -subject "site_key" -KeyExportPolicy "Exportable"`

```
   PSParentPath: Microsoft.PowerShell.Security\Certificate::LocalMachine\MY

Thumbprint                                Subject
----------                                -------
{thumbprint}                              CN=site_key
```

`$mypwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "<secret>" -Force -AsPlainText`
`Get-ChildItem -Path cert:\localMachine\my\{thumbprint} | Export-PfxCertificate -FilePath C:\site.pfx -Password $mypwd`

In `StartUp.ConfigureServices()` after `services.AddDbContext()`

```
// using System.IO;
var pfxFile = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine("folder1", "site.pfx"));

// using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
services.AddDataProtection()
        .PersistKeysToDbContext<MyKeysContext>();
        .ProtectKeysWithCertificate(new X509Certificate2(pfxFile, "<secret>"));
```

It may be necessary to delete the contents of the `DataProtectionKeys` table and restart the web app to store an encrypted key in the table.

[Microsoft doc about protecting key with certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/implementation/key-encryption-at-rest?view=aspnetcore-3.1#x509-certificate)

[Microsoft doc about protecting key with X509Certificate2 certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?view=aspnetcore-3.1#protectkeyswith)

[New-SelfSignedCertificate reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pkiclient/new-selfsignedcertificate?view=win10-ps#examples)

[Export-PfxCertificate reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pkiclient/export-pfxcertificate?view=win10-ps)