# Add-AzKeyVaultKey fails with message "Invalid provider type specified" when adding key to keyvault

Tags: powershell, import, key, azure-keyvault

I'm trying to add a key to a keyvault using Add-AzKeyVaultKey, but it fails with the message "Invalid provider type specified".

```
Add-AzKeyVaultKey : Invalid provider type specified.
At line:3 char:1
+ Add-AzKeyVaultKey -VaultName '$KeyVaultName' -Name 'alfalaval-as2-pri ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Add-AzKeyVaultKey], CryptographicException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.KeyVault.AddAzureKeyVaultKey
```

I can successfully import the certificate (from pfx) to the keyvault, but when importing the key from the same pfx the operation fails.

According to Microsoft document, it should be a pfx file (PEM not supported): [Micsosoft, Add-AzKeyVaultKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.keyvault/add-azkeyvaultkey?view=azps-5.4.0)

I've uploaded a sample dummy keypair here ([keypair at filebin](https://filebin.net/rjw7pfhyc5t2ck98)) if anyone wants to try it out.

**Sample code**

```
#Import certificate used for encryption
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "abcd1234" -AsPlainText -Force
Import-AzKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName "$KeyVaultName" -Name "as2-demo-certificate" -FilePath 'C:\mypath\as2-demo-cert.pfx' -Password $Password

#Importing key used for decryption
Add-AzKeyVaultKey -VaultName '$KeyVaultName' -Name 'as2-demo-private-key' -Destination 'Software' -KeyFilePath 'C:\mypath\as2-demo-cert.pfx' -KeyFilePassword $Password
```

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Could [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63841761/9898643) be of help?

Comment: Yes, thanks - that did the trick. I specified the provider when generating the certificate from powershell.

Comment: Great! good to hear that got it fixed. For the benefit of others, please consider posting a self-answer explaining more about this.

Comment: Of course! :)  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Theo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9898643/theo) pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63841761/9898643) (read for more details), the solution is to specify the provider when generating our keypair since the Add-AzKeyVaultKey cmdlet only supports the Cryptography Next Generation (CNG, CAPI2) provider.

Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61350156/generate-a-crypoapi-capi-private-key) another great post with even more details.

If you do not specify the provider, the New-SelfSignedCertificate cmdlet defaults to "Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider"

Supported provider: "Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider"

**Sample**

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My -KeyAlgorithm "RSA" -DnsName "test.local" -Subject "test.local" -FriendlyName "test-cng" -provider "Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider" -KeyExportPolicy "Exportable" -NotAfter (Get-Date).AddYears(10)
```

When exporting this as a pfx, the powershell cmdlet has no problem parsing it.
Would be great if the [MS Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.keyvault/add-azkeyvaultkey?view=azps-5.3.0) pointed this out - would have saved me a ton of troubleshooting :)